# In Moshiach's times will we fast on Yom Kippur

Tags: yom-kippur, messiah, beis-hamikdash

When Moshiach arrives and the Beis Hamikdash is Rebuilt and the Avodah starts again will we be required to fast on Yom Kippur? (please provide sources for your answers)

Comment: Well it says in the Torah to fast on Yom Kippur, so I don't know why that would change when mashiach comes.

Comment: They fasted the last couple times we had a temple...

Comment: [Edit]ing in why you think the Torah will change when Mashiach comes would greatly improve your question.

Comment: Hello user7156, and welcome to Mi Yodeya! Thanks for your interesting question (which, as Double AA said, could use a little more detail). Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features. You might also consider choosing a more interesting name than 7156, unless you really really like that number :P. Hope to see you around!

Comment: Honestly there is  no reason it is just the part I dread most

Comment: inspired by this? "Our Sages teach that when the Messiah arrives the festivals will cease to be observed, but Purim will continue to be observed. The Midrash (Mishlei 9) derives this unusual conclusion from a statement in Megillat Esther, (9:28) “the memory of Purim will never cease from among their descendants.”" As Y"K is a "festival" in some sense, will it be observed and is fasting part of the festival or something separate?

Comment: @Danno Yeah, that's how I took it....7156, is that where you're coming from?

Answer (score 1):

This does not mean that the festivals in the Torah will be abolished, but that the appreciation of the miracles and the redemption that occurs when the Mashiach comes and the temple is rebuilt will overshadow them. However, the Halachos of the Torah (including Yom Kippur) will continue.

As an example [chabad](http://www.shmais.com/chabad-news/latest/item/living-with-moshiach-2706) says

> The Midrash (Mishlei 9:2) teaches: "All the festivals will be annulled
>   in future time, except for Purim." The future revelation of Divinity
>   will be so intense that the revelation currently evinced by the
>   festivals will be as insignificant as a midday candle. Purim, however,
>   will be the exception, because the Purim miracle was called forth by
>   the year-long self-sacrifice of the Jewish people of that time. (They
>   could have averted Haman's decree by apostasy.) Their self-sacrifice
>   evoked a Divine reaction so sublime that even in the future time it
>   will never be annulled.

The gemoro in Rosh Hashana 18b discusses what will happen to the fasts decreed for the destruction of the temple after the temple is rebuilt and Bnei Yisroel are free of the oppression of the nations. These are the only fasts that will be changed to feasts or will be annulled.